# Pulseaudio is no longer working in Debian Squeeze: 'Failed to open module "module-combine-sink": file not found'

Tags: linux, debian, audio, pulse-audio

I'm having a problem with pulseaudio. My machine crashed, and when I rebooted and ran pavucontrol, I got a "Connection Failed: Connection refused" dialog.

When I run `pulseaudio --log-level=info --log-target=stderr` from the command line, I get the following output:

```
[...]
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device front:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC1D0c' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hw:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC1D0c' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC1D0c' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:1: No such file or directory
I: alsa-util.c: Failed to set hardware parameters on plug:iec958:1: Invalid argument
I: alsa-util.c: Failed to set hardware parameters on plug:iec958:1: Invalid argument
I: alsa-util.c: Failed to set hardware parameters on plug:iec958:1: Invalid argument
I: alsa-util.c: Failed to set hardware parameters on plug:iec958:1: Invalid argument
I: alsa-util.c: Failed to set hardware parameters on plug:iec958:1: Invalid argument
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:1
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:1
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:1
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:1
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:1
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:1
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:1
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:1
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:1
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:1
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)confmisc.c: Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=1,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: Evaluate error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM hdmi:1
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)confmisc.c: Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=1,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: Evaluate error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM hdmi:1
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)confmisc.c: Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=1,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: Evaluate error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM hdmi:1
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)confmisc.c: Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=1,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: Evaluate error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM hdmi:1
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)confmisc.c: Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=1,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: Evaluate error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM hdmi:1
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC1D0c' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hw:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC1D0c' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device front:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC1D0c' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hw:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC1D0c' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:1: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC1D0c' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:1: No such file or directory
I: card.c: Created 0 "alsa_card.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01-Audio"
I: alsa-sink.c: Successfully opened device front:1.
I: alsa-sink.c: Selected mapping 'Analog Stereo' (analog-stereo).
I: alsa-sink.c: Successfully enabled mmap() mode.
I: alsa-sink.c: Successfully enabled timer-based scheduling mode.
I: (alsa-lib)control.c: Invalid CTL front:1
I: alsa-mixer.c: Unable to attach to mixer front:1: No such file or directory
I: alsa-mixer.c: Successfully attached to mixer 'hw:1'
W: alsa-mixer.c: Your kernel driver is broken: it reports a volume range from 0.00 dB to 0.00 dB which makes no sense.
I: module-device-restore.c: Restoring volume for sink alsa_output.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01-Audio.analog-stereo.
I: sink.c: Created sink 0 "alsa_output.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01-Audio.analog-stereo" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: sink.c:     alsa.resolution_bits = "16"
I: sink.c:     device.api = "alsa"
I: sink.c:     device.class = "sound"
I: sink.c:     alsa.class = "generic"
I: sink.c:     alsa.subclass = "generic-mix"
I: sink.c:     alsa.name = "USB Audio"
I: sink.c:     alsa.id = "USB Audio"
I: sink.c:     alsa.subdevice = "0"
I: sink.c:     alsa.subdevice_name = "subdevice #0"
I: sink.c:     alsa.device = "0"
I: sink.c:     alsa.card = "1"
I: sink.c:     alsa.card_name = "DigiHug USB Audio"
I: sink.c:     alsa.long_card_name = "FiiO DigiHug USB Audio at usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2, full speed"
I: sink.c:     alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
I: sink.c:     device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.2:1.1"
I: sink.c:     sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1/sound/card1"
I: sink.c:     udev.id = "usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01-Audio"
I: sink.c:     device.bus = "usb"
I: sink.c:     device.vendor.id = "1852"
I: sink.c:     device.vendor.name = "GYROCOM C&C Co., LTD"
I: sink.c:     device.product.id = "7022"
I: sink.c:     device.product.name = "DigiHug_USB_Audio"
I: sink.c:     device.serial = "FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio"
I: sink.c:     device.string = "front:1"
I: sink.c:     device.buffering.buffer_size = "352800"
I: sink.c:     device.buffering.fragment_size = "176400"
I: sink.c:     device.access_mode = "mmap+timer"
I: sink.c:     device.profile.name = "analog-stereo"
I: sink.c:     device.profile.description = "Analog Stereo"
I: sink.c:     device.description = "DigiHug_USB_Audio Analog Stereo"
I: sink.c:     alsa.mixer_name = "USB Mixer"
I: sink.c:     alsa.components = "USB1852:7022"
I: sink.c:     module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
I: sink.c:     device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
I: source.c: Created source 0 "alsa_output.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01-Audio.analog-stereo.monitor" with sample spec s16le 2ch 44100Hz and channel map front-left,front-right
I: source.c:     device.description = "Monitor of DigiHug_USB_Audio Analog Stereo"
I: source.c:     device.class = "monitor"
I: source.c:     alsa.card = "1"
I: source.c:     alsa.card_name = "DigiHug USB Audio"
I: source.c:     alsa.long_card_name = "FiiO DigiHug USB Audio at usb-0000:00:1a.0-1.2, full speed"
I: source.c:     alsa.driver_name = "snd_usb_audio"
I: source.c:     device.bus_path = "pci-0000:00:1a.0-usb-0:1.2:1.1"
I: source.c:     sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1/sound/card1"
I: source.c:     udev.id = "usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01-Audio"
I: source.c:     device.bus = "usb"
I: source.c:     device.vendor.id = "1852"
I: source.c:     device.vendor.name = "GYROCOM C&C Co., LTD"
I: source.c:     device.product.id = "7022"
I: source.c:     device.product.name = "DigiHug_USB_Audio"
I: source.c:     device.serial = "FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio"
I: source.c:     device.string = "1"
I: source.c:     module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
I: source.c:     device.icon_name = "audio-card-usb"
I: alsa-sink.c: Using 2.0 fragments of size 176400 bytes (1000.00ms), buffer size is 352800 bytes (2000.00ms)
I: alsa-sink.c: Time scheduling watermark is 20.00ms
I: alsa-sink.c: Hardware volume ranges from 0 to 110.
I: alsa-sink.c: Using hardware volume control. Hardware dB scale not supported.
I: alsa-sink.c: Using hardware mute control.
I: core-util.c: Successfully enabled SCHED_RR scheduling for thread, with priority 5.
I: alsa-sink.c: Starting playback.
I: module.c: Loaded "module-alsa-card" (index: #4; argument: "device_id="1" name="usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01-Audio" card_name="alsa_card.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01-Audio" tsched=yes ignore_dB=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"").
I: module-udev-detect.c: Card /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.2/1-1.2:1.1/sound/card1 (alsa_card.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01-Audio) module loaded.
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hw:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hw:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hw:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hw:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hw:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device front:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hw:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device front:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hw:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device front:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hw:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device front:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hw:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device front:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hw:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround40:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround40:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround40:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround40:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround40:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround41:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround41:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround41:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround41:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround41:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround50:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround50:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround50:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround50:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround50:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround51:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround51:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround51:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround51:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround51:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround71:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround71:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround71:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround71:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device surround71:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm_hw.c: open '/dev/snd/pcmC2D0p' failed (-2)
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device iec958:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:2
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:2
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:2
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:2
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:2
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:2
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:2
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:2
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:2
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM a52:2
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device a52:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)confmisc.c: Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=2,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: Evaluate error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM hdmi:2
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)confmisc.c: Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=2,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: Evaluate error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM hdmi:2
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)confmisc.c: Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=2,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: Evaluate error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM hdmi:2
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)confmisc.c: Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=2,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: Evaluate error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM hdmi:2
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:2: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)confmisc.c: Unable to find definition 'cards.USB-Audio.pcm.hdmi.0:CARD=2,AES0=4,AES1=130,AES2=0,AES3=2'
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: function snd_func_refer returned error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)conf.c: Evaluate error: No such file or directory
I: (alsa-lib)pcm.c: Unknown PCM hdmi:2
I: alsa-util.c: Error opening PCM device hdmi:2: No such file or directory
I: alsa-util.c: Device hw:2 doesn't support 44100 Hz, changed to 8000 Hz.
I: alsa-util.c: Failed to set hardware parameters on plug:front:2: Invalid argument
I: alsa-util.c: Failed to set hardware parameters on plug:hw:2: Invalid argument
I: alsa-util.c: Failed to set hardware parameters on plug:iec958:2: Invalid argument
I: alsa-util.c: Failed to set hardware parameters on plug:iec958:2: Invalid argument
I: module-card-restore.c: Restoring profile for card alsa_card.usb-046d_08d7-01-U0x46d0x8d7.
I: card.c: Created 1 "alsa_card.usb-046d_08d7-01-U0x46d0x8d7"
I: module.c: Loaded "module-alsa-card" (index: #5; argument: "device_id="2" name="usb-046d_08d7-01-U0x46d0x8d7" card_name="alsa_card.usb-046d_08d7-01-U0x46d0x8d7" tsched=yes ignore_dB=no card_properties="module-udev-detect.discovered=1"").
I: module-udev-detect.c: Card /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.1/sound/card2 (alsa_card.usb-046d_08d7-01-U0x46d0x8d7) module loaded.
I: module-udev-detect.c: Found 3 cards.
I: module.c: Loaded "module-udev-detect" (index: #6; argument: "").
I: module.c: Loaded "module-esound-protocol-unix" (index: #7; argument: "").
I: module.c: Loaded "module-native-protocol-unix" (index: #8; argument: "").
I: module-default-device-restore.c: Saved default sink 'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-surround-41' not existant, not restoring default sink setting.
I: module-default-device-restore.c: Saved default source 'alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-surround-41.monitor' not existant, not restoring default source setting.
I: module.c: Loaded "module-default-device-restore" (index: #9; argument: "").
I: module.c: Loaded "module-rescue-streams" (index: #10; argument: "").
I: module.c: Loaded "module-always-sink" (index: #11; argument: "").
I: module.c: Loaded "module-intended-roles" (index: #12; argument: "").
I: module.c: Loaded "module-suspend-on-idle" (index: #13; argument: "").
I: client.c: Created 0 "ConsoleKit Session /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2"
I: module.c: Loaded "module-console-kit" (index: #14; argument: "").
I: module.c: Loaded "module-position-event-sounds" (index: #15; argument: "").
I: module.c: Loaded "module-cork-music-on-phone" (index: #16; argument: "").
E: module.c: Failed to open module "module-combine-sink": file not found
E: main.c: Module load failed.
E: main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
I: module.c: Unloading "module-device-restore" (index: #0).
I: module.c: Unloaded "module-device-restore" (index: #0).
I: module.c: Unloading "module-stream-restore" (index: #1).
I: module.c: Unloaded "module-stream-restore" (index: #1).
I: module.c: Unloading "module-card-restore" (index: #2).
I: module.c: Unloaded "module-card-restore" (index: #2).
I: module.c: Unloading "module-augment-properties" (index: #3).
I: module.c: Unloaded "module-augment-properties" (index: #3).
I: module.c: Unloading "module-alsa-card" (index: #4).
I: sink.c: Freeing sink 0 "alsa_output.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01-Audio.analog-stereo"
I: source.c: Freeing source 0 "alsa_output.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01-Audio.analog-stereo.monitor"
I: card.c: Freed 0 "alsa_card.usb-FiiO_DigiHug_USB_Audio-01-Audio"
I: module.c: Unloaded "module-alsa-card" (index: #4).
I: module.c: Unloading "module-alsa-card" (index: #5).
I: card.c: Freed 1 "alsa_card.usb-046d_08d7-01-U0x46d0x8d7"
I: module.c: Unloaded "module-alsa-card" (index: #5).
I: module.c: Unloading "module-udev-detect" (index: #6).
I: module.c: Unloaded "module-udev-detect" (index: #6).
I: module.c: Unloading "module-esound-protocol-unix" (index: #7).
I: module.c: Unloaded "module-esound-protocol-unix" (index: #7).
I: module.c: Unloading "module-native-protocol-unix" (index: #8).
I: module.c: Unloaded "module-native-protocol-unix" (index: #8).
I: module.c: Unloading "module-default-device-restore" (index: #9).
I: module.c: Unloaded "module-default-device-restore" (index: #9).
I: module.c: Unloading "module-rescue-streams" (index: #10).
I: module.c: Unloaded "module-rescue-streams" (index: #10).
I: module.c: Unloading "module-always-sink" (index: #11).
I: module.c: Unloaded "module-always-sink" (index: #11).
I: module.c: Unloading "module-intended-roles" (index: #12).
I: module.c: Unloaded "module-intended-roles" (index: #12).
I: module.c: Unloading "module-suspend-on-idle" (index: #13).
I: module.c: Unloaded "module-suspend-on-idle" (index: #13).
I: module.c: Unloading "module-console-kit" (index: #14).
I: client.c: Freed 0 "ConsoleKit Session /org/freedesktop/ConsoleKit/Session2"
I: module.c: Unloaded "module-console-kit" (index: #14).
I: module.c: Unloading "module-position-event-sounds" (index: #15).
I: module.c: Unloaded "module-position-event-sounds" (index: #15).
I: module.c: Unloading "module-cork-music-on-phone" (index: #16).
I: module.c: Unloaded "module-cork-music-on-phone" (index: #16).
I: main.c: Daemon terminated.
```

I believe the relevant part is this:

```
E: module.c: Failed to open module "module-combine-sink": file not found
E: main.c: Module load failed.
E: main.c: Failed to initialize daemon.
```

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling pulseaudio, I tried to find a way to install module-combine-sink. Nothing worked. I'm on a Debian Squeeze 32-bit machine.

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue (except with "module-cork-music-on-phone" - my Wheezy install just had this on 2012-06-02).

The problem is what the error message says - pulseaudio is trying to load a module that's not present.

Edit the `~/.pulse/default.pa` and/or `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and comment out the offending "load module" lines with a `#` and the problem goes away.

Downgrading the offending package(s) is another possible fix if the above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the device drivers are not loading for the sound card.

Try re-configuring alsa, `alsactl init` and reboot.

**EDIT**: From your reply it sounds like the kernel package was updated before the crash, and now the new kernel or alsa-base package is giving you problems.  There are a [bunch of open bugs](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?package=alsa-base) specific to Intel HD Audio driver.

My recommendation is to reboot and select the previous kernel.  You may need to do run `altactl init` again, but it should work.

The other option (which is what I would do) is install the [official driver from RealTek](http://www.realtek.com/downloads/downloadsCheck.aspx?Langid=1&PNid=24&PFid=24&Level=4&Conn=3&DownTypeID=3&GetDown=false).

Comment: `# sudo alsactl init
Unknown hardware: "HDA-Intel" "Realtek ALC889" "HDA:10ec0889,14627588,00100004" "0x1462" "0x7588"
Hardware is initialized using a guess method`

Comment: Updated answer.  I'm pretty sure you're running into updated driver issues.